# Excel 2010 Removing duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to remove the duplicates items from a big Excel sheet.
I would like to remove all rows that have a duplicate code values (sample below)

Before:

```
Name     Code
item_01  xxxx01
item_02  xxxx02
item_03  xxxx01
item_01  xxxx03
item_04  xxxx04
```

After:

```
Name     Code
item_01  xxxx01
item_02  xxxx02
item_01  xxxx03
item_04  xxxx04
```

I have played with the "Remove Duplicates" features, but I can't get the result that I want.

Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not explained "the result that I want", but I will take a shot at this.

When you select both columns then click `Remove Duplicates` from the Data ribbon, the below dialog window opens. Remove the check box from the column you DO NOT want the duplicates removed and then click `OK`.

[image]

It results in the example you gave above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a helper column next to column B, to count the number of duplicates like this:

```
=COUNTIF($B:$B,B1)
```

Copy that down till the end of column B. Use the autoFilter option on column C, to filter out the duplicates systematically. Remove the rows manually afterwards.

Comment: Thanks Jacob,
This is not exactly the answer that I was waiting for but it guided me on the good path to the explanation.

My file is resulting from many manipulation and data import. As a result, I have some cells with the same value but sometimes considered as text and sometimes as number.

Consequence, Excel does not match them.

Comment: @AlbanSoupper: thanks for your reply and good luck.