# Removing duplicates from txt file

Tags: csv, deduplication

I have a txt file that can contain up to 13.000.000 randomly generated codes seperated with "\n" by the fputcsv function in php.

What is the most effective way of removing duplicates from this file?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel 2010 Removing duplicates](http://superuser.com/questions/518751/excel-2010-removing-duplicates)

Comment: @SeanClt I have tried with excell. It crashes.

Comment: Excel is the software xls and csv are just file format same solution applies

Comment: @SeanClt the OP has 13 MILLION records. The hard limit for rows in Excel 2010 is 1 million.

Comment: If not excel then it would have to be done using vb code programmatically

Comment: @MadsAnkerNielsen - Write a small program that loads the file into blocks, an easy way to avoid memory issues is to first determine how many records there are, then determine break it into smaller chunks.  Once you have broken the file into chunks, you can load each file in batches, creating a merged document which does not contain duplicates.  *You are talking 200 lines of code at most.*

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe your file format better. It is unclear whether these code are all on one line or on multiple lines. Why do you say 'amount of code can vary'? I can interpret that as *per line* (in that case: give a larger sample) or *this files (these files?) is repeatedly generated so I must automate this process*. What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that Excel has a limit of [1,048,576 rows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1#bmworksheetworkbook) and your dataset has 13 million entries. Each entry should be on a separate line.

Assuming you are on Windows you can use a program called [NotePad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to find and remove duplicates. The answer over on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16293580/2505109) suggests using either a regular expression or a plugin.

I would use the regular expression option. Below is a brief summary from the SO answer.

1. Ensure each entry is on a single line
2. Open the find and replace
3. Select the regular expression mode
4. Enter the expression `^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)` into the search box
5. Leave the replacement box empty
6. Click Replace All

If this data is an export from a database you might want to consider amending your SQL statement prior to the export by adding `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) for an example.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and use better terminology. You are confusing *lines*, *rows*, *columns* and *records*. It does not help, of course, that the OP asks an unclear question - maybe wait for him/her to clean it up.

Comment: I haven't mentioned columns at all! ;) I take your point though.

Comment: I tested this on a small file i wrote, looking like this(123 newline 123 newline 124.....) and i sucsessfully removed "123". But when i try this on my large file it removes the whole thing. What am i doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @MadsAnkerNielsen the SO answer mentions that ticking or unticking the "`.` equates to a newline" may resolve that.

Comment: My final solution was to use a plugin called textFX. So your answer was not the exact solution, but you send me on the right track.